# Sorting Array models in ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frontend

I have question, what should I do to make sorting working in Ember app?
I created simple blog app via ember-cli

Model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    publishedAt: DS.attr('date'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Route structure is:

```
this.resource('blog', function() {
        this.route('new');
        ...
 });
```

And in **blog/index** I have `{{#each blog in model}}` looping for all data

I added controller **blog/index**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortAscending: true,
    sortProperties: ['date']
});
```

And nothing seems to work..

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is correct, but I personally prefer to collapse this into a single line:

```
sortProperties: ['publishedAt:desc']
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you can add additional sorts to the array without worrying about ascending/descending setting at the Controller level.

Answer (score 0):

youre sorting by a property that doesnt exist on the model     `sortProperties: ['date']`
You need to sort by a model property:

```
sortAscending: false,    
sortProperties: ['publishedAt']
```

Comment: You are right, but just before i tried changing it to ['publishedAt'] and still nothing happend.
Maybe problem is in routes?

Comment: what do you mean nothing happened? Nothing at all displayed or the displayed information wasnt sorted?

Comment: was sorted 'default' from the oldest to the newest
(i wanted to show posts from the newest to the oldest)

Comment: change sortAscending to false - default sort is `sortAscending: true` so if you want to change it change it to false